# Trying to spawn docker containers from 'master' Java program and setting up a connection between the master and the slaves

Tags: java, docker, port

I have a java program, the master, that spawns Docker containers containing a slave server.

My master needs to be able to connect to each slave inside the Docker containers. Right now the master can connect to a slave on port `9001` by exposing that port and via the local IP of my computer, but this is a bad way to do this.

Does someone know a correct way?
My java program is spawning servers by dropping commands in the command-line like this:

```
executeCommand("docker run -p 192.168.195.1:9001:9001 " + dockerImageName);
```

Comment: This has both massive security and scalability problems: don't do it!  (...say I set `dockerImageName` to `-v/:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow`...)

Comment: I think the best way to control Docker containers from any programming language is through the Docker API (https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/). Once you have the Docker containers up and running I see no reason why you would treat them differently as if they were a seperate API endpoint.

Comment: There is also a library for Java to talk to the Docker API which helps you avoid reinventing the wheel: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java

Comment: One possible "correct" way would be to run everything (master and slave) in docker and control all this through docker-compose, not from the master itself.

Comment: What if you have multiple slaves ? You won't be able to use same port (on host) for every containers (9001)